2D Laplace equation with boundary value in the form of fundamental solution
I am trying to solve the following Boundary Value Problem (BVP) of Laplace equation in 2D
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \Delta u(x)&=0 && \quad \quad x\in \Omega \\
 u(x)&=g(x) && \quad \quad x\in\partial\Omega
\end{alignat*}
Specifically, the boundary value $g(x)$ is in the form of fundamental solution, i.e.,
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\frac{1}{|x-x_0|}$$
for some random $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
If $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\Omega$, then we know $u(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\frac{1}{|x-x_0|}$ is the solution to the BVP, since the Laplace of fundamental solution is Dirac delta function, which is zero in $\Omega$.
However, what happens if $x_0\in \Omega$? I assume the behavior will be very different. A special case is: $\Omega$ is the unit disk and $x_0=(0,0)$ is the origin. Then the solution should be constant zero function $u(x)=0$, because $g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log 1\equiv 0$ on $\partial\Omega$.
My question is: what is the general behavior for $x_0\in \Omega$? Can we come up with some analytic solution?

Without any information about $\Omega$ you won't be able to construct a solution.
